# Parsing JSON In Perl

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to parse JSON data in Perl. it is request to Cisco Prime Service. My script works, but parsing doesn't work. And I have a warning,

```
         malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "HTTP::Response=HASH(...") at InternetBSP.pl line 39.
```

It is here:

```
      my $json_text = $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode($res);
```

have no Idee how should I fix it...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON -support_by_pp;
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use REST::Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

#So dass es auch ohne SSL Sertifizierung funktioniert

BEGIN { $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0 }

#Create a user agent object

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts => {
        SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
        verify_hostname => 0,
    }
);

#Create a request

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'https://10.10.10.10/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPoints.json?.full=true' );
$req->content_type('application/json');
$req->authorization_basic( "Username", "Password" );

#Pass request to the user agent and get a response back

my $res = $ua->request($req);

#Check the outcome of the Response

if ( $res->is_success ) {
    print $res->content;
} else {
    print $res->status_line, "n";
}

my $json      = new JSON;
my $json_text = $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode($res);

#my try to pasre the data

foreach my $ap ( @{ $json_text->{queryResponse}->{'entity'} } ) {
    print "------------------------\nAccess Point " . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'@id'} . "\n";
    print "Model:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'model'} . "\n";
    print "MAC Address:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'macAddress'} . "\n";
    print "Serial Number:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'serialNumber'} . "\n";
    print "Software Version:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'softwareVersion'} . "\n";
    print "Status:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'status'} . "\n";
    print "Location:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'location'} . "\n";
}
```

I have this like outcome:

```
   {"queryResponse":{"@last":"7","@first":"0","@count":"8","@type":"AccessPoints","@responseType":"listEntityInstances","@requestUrl":"https:\/\/10.66.1.23\/webacs\/api\/v1\/                                    data\/AccessPoints?.full=true","@rootUrl":"https:\/\/10.66.1.23\/webacs\/api\/v1\/data","entity":[{"@dtoType":"accessPointsDTO","@type":"AccessPoints","@url":"https:\/\/10                                    .66.1.23\/webacs\/api\/v1\/data\/AccessPoints\/205320"
```

But it shoud be smth like:

```
     {"queryResponse":
{"@type":"AccessPoints",
 "@rootUrl":"https://172.18.138.90/webacs/api/v1/data",
 "@requestUrl":"https://172.18.138.90/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPoints?.full=true",
 "@responseType":"listEntityInstances",
 "entity":[
    {"@url":"https://172.18.138.90/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPoints/13544533",
     "@type":"AccessPoints",
     "@dtoType":"accessPointsDTO",
     "accessPointsDTO":
        {"@id":"13544533",
         "@displayName":"13544533",
         "adminStatus":"ENABLE",
         "bootVersion":"12.4.23.0",
         "clientCount":0,
```

After update :)

```
   ------------------------
   Access Point 205320
   Model:AIR-LAP1142N-E-K9
   MAC Address:6c:9c:ed:b5:45:60
   Serial Number:FCZ1544W51B
   Software Version:7.6.130.0
   Status:CLEARED
   Location:de.bw.stu.
  ------------------------
   Access Point 205322
   Model:AIR-CAP3502I-E-K9
   MAC Address:0c:f5:a4:ee:70:10
   Serial Number:FCZ184680VB
   Software Version:7.6.130.0
   Status:CLEARED
   Location:de.bw.stu.
   ------------------------
   Access Point 205324
   Model:AIR-LAP1142N-E-K9
   MAC Address:6c:9c:ed:86:9d:20
   Serial Number:FCZ1544W50Y
   Software Version:7.6.130.0
   Status:CLEARED
   Location:de.bw.stu.
```

Comment: You should really indent your code. It's very hard to read.

Comment: Thank you for advice! :)
I'll try!

Comment: I formatted it for you using [perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/). Have a look at that tool, it's great!

Comment: @PerlDuck lots of Germans around today. StayCalm, you might want to drop by #perlde on irc.perl.org some time, the German Perl community is quite nice.

Comment: Thank you, @PerlDuck. I'll look throught

Comment: @simbabque, I'm just beginner und I write my Project work in Perl. It is "Das neu Land" for me :)
But it is really cool, that so many nice people are here...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "**HTTP::Response**=HASH(...")

This error message means that the data you are giving to `decode` is not JSON.

You are passing `$res` to `decode`, which is an [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object (see above, emphasis mine). You need to use `$res->content`, which you use for debugging output a few lines above.

> ```
>  if ($res->is_success) {
>   print $res->content;
>   } else {print $res->status_line, "n";
>   }
> ```

I would rewrite that whole block of code to this.

```
die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref
    ->utf8->relaxed
    ->escape_slash->loose
    ->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey;
my $json_text = $json->decode( $res->content );
```

Instead of printing some debug output and then going on anyway if things went wrong you can just `die` if the request was not successful.

After that, create your JSON object and configure it. This is way more readable than this long line of code, and we're using a method call to `new` instead of *indirect object notation*.

Finally, we are `decode`ing `$res->content`.

Comment: Bah, beat me to it. Might be worth adding mention how the error messages actually says this though :)

Comment: @Sobrique sorry about that. I'm lurking and waiting. :) Better?

Comment: Like that?
 #Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
       `my $res = $ua->request($req);
      $res->content; `